# Connection details are unavailable while the database is being provisioned Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, knex.js, strapi

I have trouble with the database connection. The application (Node.js/Strapi) can not be reaching to the database. We couldn’t see even the connection strings or database username/password. Currently using Digital Ocean Apps platform. (Webservice Node.js/Postgresql)

Database component shows use the following error:

```
Connection details are unavailable while the database is being provisioned.
```

In the meantime, I’ve disabled the “trusted connection” mark yesterday, could this be the cause of the problem? Now, I can not mark again, it doesn’t exist.

Related post: https://forum.strapi.io/t/digitalocean-database-connection-failed/1339

Database Component:
[image]

Node.js Error:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who's also stuck with this problem, you might need to add the environment variables for your Node.js application to make your application run before seeing the database credentials from UI, for example:

Add a `DATABASE_URL` with value `{db.DATABASE_URL}` (suppose your database service name is `db`)

[image]

See more DO dev database variables: https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/use-environment-variables/#databases

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this when connecting API server component to [App Platform](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform) development database. This can also cause in case API server component failed to deploy, since attached API server component must be successfully deployed before accessing the database.

This may be due to use database container being a dependency of API server component.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and add a fallback database connection string helped to get the application up and running and the provisioned database connection string was automatically applied when the database was up and running.

Faced the issue when deploying django after following this [article](https://docs.digitalocean.com/developer-center/deploy-a-django-app-on-app-platform/)